# Group by key and return only one of the resulting rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in a simple table:

```
ID | TYPE
---------
1  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 1
4  | 2
4  | 3
5  | 1
5  | 3
6  | 3
```

I now need to query this data in the following way:

- For each ID, only one row should be returned

  - If there is only one row for the ID return it.
  - If there are multiple rows for the ID, return the one with TYPE = 2. If that doesn't exist, return the one with TYPE = 3.
- TYPE can be either 1, 2 or 3
- ID and TYPE have a composite unique index, meaning that per ID there can be a maximum of three rows.

Question: How would I put this logic in a query?

---

Expected result:

```
ID | TYPE
---------
1  | 2
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 3
```

Comment: If there's a TYPE 1,2,3 for ID# 1 what should be returned? TYPE 2?

Comment: If type = 2 exists, return that row, even if type = 1 or type = 3 exists. If type = 2 does not exist, return type = 3 if it exists, otherwise type = 1.

Comment: @MichaelBuen: Please see updated question with updated input and expected result tables.

Comment: I see it just now. Here's my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12040369/11432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has analytic functions in all recent versions.

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                           ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 2 THEN 1
                                              WHEN 3 THEN 2
                                              WHEN 1 THEN 3 END) AS sequenced_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

With this technique you will return all the values in the table, rather than just the PrimaryKey and the search value.

**EDIT:**

The best way of dealing with that is to have another table that has the order of preference for each type.

```
 type | preference_value
------+------------------
  2   |         1
  3   |         2
  1   |         3
```

This states that `2` is the most preferential, `3` is the second preference, and `1` is the third preference.

Because it's such a small group, however, it can also be done just with a simple `CASE` statement.  See my amended query above.

Comment: Thanks. As stated in my comment to RedFilter, my question was a bit too simplistic. Can you please have a look at the update?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9957d/4

```
select id, 
    case when sum(case when type = 2 then 1 end) = 1 then
       2
    else
       max(type)
    end   
from tbl
group by id
order by id
```

Output:

```
| ID | TYPE |
-------------
|  1 |    2 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    2 |
|  4 |    2 |
|  5 |    3 |
|  6 |    3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, minimizes the CASE WHEN branching: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9957d/17

```
select id, 

    coalesce( sum(case when type=2 then 2 end), max(type) ) as type

from tbl
group by id
order by id
```

Output:

```
| ID | TYPE |
-------------
|  1 |    2 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    2 |
|  4 |    2 |
|  5 |    3 |
|  6 |    3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know there are no `TYPE` values higher than 2, you can just do this:

```
select ID, max(TYPE) as TYPE
from MyTable
group by ID
```

Comment: Not obviously, you explicitly stated there could only be a value of 1 or 2 for `TYPE`.

Comment: I meant my example was too simplistic. Your answer was perfect for my simple example. Problem is, my simple example didn't quite contain all the problems I face and so I can't use your elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id, type from
(
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by abs(2.25-type) ) as rn
   from yourtable
)v
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty obscure and wouldn't work if TYPE=1 would have a higher priority than TYPE=3, would it?

Comment: If you wanted type 1 to have a higher priority, change 2.25 to 1.75. Or you could make a lookup table for type with an ordering column, which would be a purer way to do this, rather than relying on some obscure logic of your own making :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the lookup table. That's what I ended up doing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12040592/572644. I accepted Dems answer as he fleshed this suggestion out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a little hack.

```
SELECT ID, IF(SUM(TYPE) IN (5, 6), 2, MAX(TYPE)) AS TYPE
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Having fun with `MOD()` function:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MOD(MIN(MOD(type+1,3))+1,3)+1 AS type
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY
    id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by podiluska and Dems, I am now using this:

```
with type_order as
(
    select 1 as type, 0 as prio from dual
    union all
    select 2 as type, 2 as prio from dual
    union all
    select 3 as type, 1 as prio from dual
)
select id, type from 
( 
   select yt.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by o.prio desc) as rn 
   from yourtable yt
   inner join type_order o on yt.type = o.type
)v 
where rn=1
```

This is very intention revealing and simple to extend. If there will be more types in the future, this `type_order` inline view can be refactored into a real table.